# Get the balance of SPL Tokens from a connected wallet to a DAPP

Tags: solana-program

could someone help me with this:?

I've been trying to get the amount of tokens of a connected wallet from a TokenAccount.

Right Below you can see that I successfully retrieved the TokenAccount address and the spl tokens supply but I don't know what's next...

I want to get only the amount of SPL TOKENS from the wallet connected to my DAPP. Ty and have a good day.

```
            // Check for Solana & Phantom
            var provider = () => {
            if ("solana" in window) {
                var provider = window.solana;
                if (provider.isPhantom) {
                return provider;
                } else {
                return false;
                }
            }
            window.open("https://phantom.app", "_blank");
            };

            var phantom = provider();

            if (phantom !== false) {

console.log("Phantom Wallet Found, Connecting..");

try {

                // Connect to Solana
                var connect_wallet = phantom.connect();

                // After Connecting
                phantom.on("connect", () => {
                    conn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        user_balance.classList.toggle('expand');
                    })

                  // Check Connection
                console.log("Phantom Connected: " + phantom.isConnected);

                  // Get Wallet Address
                const wallet = phantom.publicKey;
                var wallet_address = phantom.publicKey.toString();
                console.log("Solana Wallet Address: " + wallet_address);
                var first = wallet_address.substring(0, 5);
                document.getElementById('wallet-address').innerHTML = first + '...';

                (async () => {
                    const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"),
                        'confirmed',
                    );
                
                    if (phantom && phantom.publicKey !== null) {
                        const tokenAccount = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(
                            "J3Lw33iBvMLHdCua4MXohTx3HD4JcajQmogQEr2Y7pej"
                          );
                        
                          let tokenAmount = await connection.getTokenAccountBalance(tokenAccount);
                          console.log(`amount: ${tokenAmount.value.amount}`);
      
                        const balance = await connection.getBalance(phantom.publicKey);
                        console.log(balance / 1000000000);
                    }
                })();
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you right, your code works, but you need to get the TokenAccount address from the wallet right?

What you can do is: call getTokenAccountsByOwner(pubKey) and then check all the token accounts TokenAccountInfo mint if its the mint of your specific token.

Then you can call getTokenAccountBalance on that account like you already do.

To make it more performant you can directly specify the mint in the getTokenAccountsByOwner function. Then you can save the token account in the client and only call getTokenAccountBalance form then on.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying...

The thing i don't know how to do it's this:

I want the balance from a wallet connected to my DAPP but only the balance from this address "J3Lw33iBvMLHdCua4MXohTx3HD4JcajQmogQEr2Y7pej" at the wallet that connected to my site

To give a little more info:

I want to get the SPL TOKEN BALANCE but from the wallet connected... not the Token Account wallet which is this... "J3Lw33iBvMLHdCua4MXohTx3HD4JcajQmogQEr2Y7pej"

Comment: Yeah so as long as J3Lw33iBvMLHdCua4MXohTx3HD4JcajQmogQEr2Y7pej is the mint authority of your spl token what i wrote should do exactly that. Did you try it out?

Comment: I've tried but i can't find a way to connect the SPL token `TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID` directly at Vanilla JS... any advice? ty

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the question. "connect the SPL token TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID directly at Vanilla JS" Cant figure out what that could mean.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this snippet myself

```
export const getTokenBalance = async (walletAddress:string, tokenMintAddress:string):Promise<number> => {
  try{
    const connection = new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_RPC_ENDPOINT, 'confirmed')
    const walletTokenAccounts = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(new PublicKey(walletAddress), {
      mint: new PublicKey(tokenMintAddress)
    })
    if(walletTokenAccounts && walletTokenAccounts.value && walletTokenAccounts.value.length > 0){
      const walletTokenAccount = walletTokenAccounts.value[0]
      const amount = walletTokenAccount.account.data.parsed.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount
      console.log(`amount: ${amount}`);
      return amount
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e)
  }
  return 0
}
```

`walletAddress` would be your `wallet_address`
`tokenMintAddress` would be the address of the SPL token. For example if you were looking to get the balance of BONK, you would use `DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263`